# Changing the height of a line break generated by "white-space: normal"

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I have a  tag with its contents being displayed normally until the screen size gets pretty small. The problem is that once the text eventually gets split into to "rows", the text overlaps itself.

This is how it currently looks:
[Overlapping Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnxwt.png)

Would really appreciate some help, If I try to keep it in the same line, the text will overlap with the similar text to it's right.

I don't think I really have any relevant CSS-properties I can include, but let me know if I can provide any more relevant info. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: adjust `line-height`

Comment: Looks like a `line-height` issue to me but can't give you any more suggestions without some working code

Comment: Perfect muchachos, thanks a bunch... such an easy fix ':)